# How do I know if I can disable SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Every time I run my app that uses Flask-SQLAlchemy I get the following warning that the `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS` option will be disabled.

```
/home/david/.virtualenvs/flask-sqlalchemy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:800: UserWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.')
```

I tried to find out what this option does, but the Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation isn't clear about what uses this tracking.

> `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS`
>
> If set to True (the default) Flask-SQLAlchemy will track modifications of objects and emit signals. This requires extra memory and can be disabled if not needed.

How do I find out if my project requires `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True` or if I can safely disable this feature and save memory on my server?

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Most likely your application doesn't use the Flask-SQLAlchemy event system, so you're probably safe to turn off. You'll need to audit the code to verify--you're looking for anything that hooks into [`models_committed` or `before_models_committed`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/dev/signals/). If you do find that you're using the Flask-SQLAlchemy event system, you probably should update the code to use SQLAlchemy's built-in event system instead.

The default value as of Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.1 is `None`, which is a falsy value, so the event system *is disabled*. In older versions, the default value was `True`, so you'll need to explicitly disable it.

However, in both cases, the warning won't be silenced until this is explicitly set to `False`. To do that, add:

```
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

to your app config.

---

Background--here's what the warning is telling you:

Flask-SQLAlchemy has its own event notification system that gets layered on top of SQLAlchemy. To do this, it tracks modifications to the SQLAlchemy session. This takes extra resources, so the option `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS` allows you to disable the modification tracking system.

The rationale for the change is three-fold:

1. Not many people use Flask-SQLAlchemy's event system, but most people don't realize they can save system resources by disabling it. So a saner default is to disable it and those who want it can turn it on.
2. The event system in Flask-SQLAlchemy has been rather buggy (see issues linked to in the pull request mentioned below), requiring additional maintenance for a feature that few people use.
3. In v0.7, SQLAlchemy itself added a [powerful event system](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html) including the ability to create custom events. Ideally, the Flask-SQLAlchemy event system should do nothing more than create a few custom SQLAlchemy event hooks and listeners, and then let SQLAlchemy itself manage the event trigger.

You can see more in the discussion around [the pull request that started triggering this warning](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/256).

Comment: For the record, the actual variable you want to set to True or False to avoid this printout is `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']`, where app is your flask app created using `flask.Flask()`

Comment: In general that's true; however if you're configuring using an object pattern or file it might be a little different (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/config/). But if you're doing that, you probably already know how to configure variables in your app.

Comment: From version 2.1 (Oct 2015), the default value of `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS` is `None` instead of `True`. Check out [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65101693/5511849) from 2020.

Answer (score 119):

Jeff Widman's detailed explanation is simply perfect.

Since I had some copy'n'paste fights before getting this right I'd like to make it easier for the next one that will be in my shoes.

The needed configuration must be added in your code, between:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

and:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

If you want to enable track modifications add:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
```

Otherwise, if you are *not* using this feature, you may want to change the value to False:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

This will silence the warning anyway since you're explicitly setting the parameter in your configuration.

The final result should look similar to this example:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

**Note**
Please keep in mind that currently (**July 2022**) SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS defaults to **None** so there is *no risk of memory loss* related if you don't configure it.
Anyhow, if you want to suppress the warning, you will have to choose between True and False in your config.

Thanks to Jeff Widman for this added suggestion and details.

Comment: @Pitto this is what I was looking for . Indeed SQLAlchemy event system is spot on for most part of it. Additional on Flask-SQLAlchemy have never used. Just using for a sample app. Kudos to the team to create deprecation warning. Really helpful.
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

Answer (score 10):

The above answers look good.  However, I wanted to point out this line in the Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation because I was still getting these warnings after setting `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False` in my application config.

On this page:  http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/config/

> The following configuration values exist for Flask-SQLAlchemy. Flask-SQLAlchemy loads these values from your main Flask config which can be populated in various ways. Note that some of those cannot be modified after the engine was created so make sure to configure as early as possible and to not modify them at runtime.

In other words, make sure to set up your `app.config` *before* creating your Flask-SQLAlchemy database.

For example, if you are configuring your application to set `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False`:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Answer (score 8):

**Answer from 2020**

If you have questions like this, then you definitely don't need this feature.

By the way, the top answer is outdated. From version 2.1 (released on Oct 23, 2015), this config `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS` defaults to `None`. That's mean the tracking behavior defaults to disabled, you don't need to worry about memory loss.

Unless you are bothered with the terminal warning, you can suppress the warning by setting it to `False`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to set your app config properties BEFORE you pass the app to SqlAlchemy. Below is an example of setting up a connection to sql server.

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)
SERVER = 'MY_DB_SERVER'
DATABASE = 'MY_DB_NAME'
USERNAME = 'MY_DOMAIN\\MY_USERNAME'
PASSWORD = '$ecretsSecretsarenofun...' # the office ref iykyk
DRIVER = 'SQL SERVER'
DATABASE_CONNECTION = f'MSSQL://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{SERVER}/{DATABASE}?driver={DRIVER};trusted_connection=yes'

app = Flask(__name__)

# set your config properties BEFORE passing the app to SQLAlchemy
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DATABASE_CONNECTION
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by copy-pasting this onto your shell:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

Comment: The question was not how to disable this warning but who to decide if the value should be set to `True` or `False`.