# AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'datetime'

Tags: python, flask

Im following a youtube tutorial on using Flask and when i run this code by using `python -m flask run` it shows this AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'datetime'. How can I fix it?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from datetime import datetime as dt

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.datetime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r' % self.id

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: please show full traceback

Comment: the traceback is very long that when I try to add the full part, it is requiring me to add more details. But last few lines look like this  File "C:\Users\home\PycharmProjects\Flaskintroduction\app.py", line 11, in <module>
    class Todo(db.Model):
  File "C:\Users\home\PycharmProjects\Flaskintroduction\app.py", line 14, in Todo
    date_created = db.Column(db.datetime, default=datetime.utcnow)
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLALchemy adds significant overload. SQLAlchemy Object has no attribute 'dateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57424146/sqlalchemy-adds-significant-overload-sqlalchemy-object-has-no-attribute-dateti)

Comment: oh yes it works thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column types are classes and capitalized. Try this:

```
db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Notice `DateTime`, not `datetime`.