# Unexpected Warnings about SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_BINDS and SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making an app with a cache, and it works fine. But the problem is I keep getting these warnings when I shouldn't get them. These are the warnings:

```py
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\meon-dashboard\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:812: UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\meon-dashboard\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:833: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
```

And I have them set as you can see from this piece of code:

```py
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///configs/cache.sqlite3"
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting these warnings and how to make them not appear?

(I tried setting `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']` as `True` as well but it didnt work.)

Comment: [This answer that I found googling `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39794504/14016161) says you have to set this option "**immediately after**" creating the `Flask` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///configs/cache.sqlite3"
```

It should be:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///configs/cache.sqlite3"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

You can read more about it here:

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/signals/

Also, `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS` will be set to `False` by default, starting from version `3.0.0` (unreleased):

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/master/changelog/#version-3-0-0

As of this writing, current version is `2.4.4`:

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/master/changelog/#version-2-4-4